# Compiling and running a "hello world" program in PETSc

Tags: petsc, compiling, mpi

I'm trying to compile a hello world program using PETSc, based off of [this tutorial, slide 33](http://acts.nersc.gov/events/Workshop2002/slides/Smith.pdf) .  How would I compile this?  I know that I can't use a simple 'mpicc' command.  When running the program, would I use the standard mpirun or mpiexec?

Comment: did you include this at the beginning of the makefile ? CFLAGS = -I${PETSC_DIR}/include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slides from 2002 are ancient. Have a look at newer tutorials at http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/tutorials/index.html

To answer your question, though, you will want to look at some of the examples in, say, `$PETSC_DIR/src/ksp/ksp/examples/tutorials`. In particular, the makefile is how to compile an example program.

A short example to compile `hello.c`:

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/rules

hello: hello.o  chkopts
    -${CLINKER} -o hello hello.o  ${PETSC_LIB}
    ${RM} hello.o
```

You would then run:

`export PETSC_DIR=/path/to/petsc` and `export PETSC_ARCH=petsc-arch`

Please review the installation instructions:

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html

After a successful installation of PETSc, run your own test:

`make hello`

A good tip for debugging (where you want to leave the .o files around) is to run:

`make hello RM=echo`

Comment: Shouldn't there be a hello.c somewhere in the makefile?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  I keep getting this error:  /bin/sh: LINKER}: command not found.

Comment: @Paul: When you added the new line, did you remember to put a `$` in front of `LINKER`?

Comment: @Dan: You were almost right... there was a '{' missing before the LINKER.  Now that i've changed it, I get a slightly different error:  hello.c:1:19: error: petsc.h: No such file or directory  I'm thinking that there's some problem with the path to the petsc.h file.

Comment: You might need to include `petscksp.h`.

Comment: @Paul: No, there should not be a hello.c in your makefile. PETSc makefiles define their own implicit rule for .c files

Comment: @Paul: Please paste the full error, else I have no idea what's going on. Just shooting in the dark, but did you make sure to define PETSC_DIR and PETSC_ARCH?